# How to search more than one option in Sunspot?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sunspot

Using [Sunspot](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot#readme), I have the following setup:

**Search Form**

```
<div>
Search field
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>

Online
<%= check_box_tag :online_search, 'online_search_value', 
                                   params[:online_search_checked] %>

Street Address
<%= text_field_tag :location, params[:search_loc] %>
</div>
```

**Search Controller**

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController

  def index
    params[:online_search_checked] = true 
    restore_cookie 
  end

  def results
    update_cookie 
    restore_cookie 
    @search = Product.search do |q| 
      q.fulltext params[:search] unless params[:search].blank?

      # Text field to search an address.
      q.with(:location).near(params[:search_loc]) 
                       if params[:search_loc].present?

      # Checkbox thats already checked off to search online.
      # If it's un-checked It will not search online.
      q.with(:online_search, false) if params[:online_search].nil?

    end
    @products = @search.results 
  end

  def update_cookie 
    update_cookie_with_param(:online_search, :online_search_checked)
  end

  def restore_cookie 
    restore_param_from_cookie(:online_search_checked)
  end

  def update_cookie_with_param(value_param_name, checked_param_name)
    checked = params[value_param_name].nil? ? "false" : "true"
    cookies[checked_param_name] = { :value => 
                                checked, :expires => 2.weeks.from_now } 
  end

  def restore_param_from_cookie(checked_param_name)
    if cookies[checked_param_name] 
      params[checked_param_name] = (cookies[checked_param_name] == "true")
    end
  end
end
```

When searching a `:location`, I want it to include `:online_search` unless the user un-checks the checkbox. This is what this line does:

```
q.with(:online_search, false) if params[:online_search].nil?
```

Now to include it with searching a `:location`. How would I go about doing this with Sunspot?

Comment: I believe the unchecked checkbox won't be passed into your params if it isn't checked.  I would think simply doing `if params[:online_search]`, etc... would work just fine.

Comment: @johnernaut I'm not fully understanding what you mean. You can also make this an answer if you would like.

Comment: `params[:online_search]` shouldn't be submitted if it wasn't checked.  Try just doing `if params[:online_search] ... q.with(:online_search) ... end`.  Let me know if that works and I'll make an answer.

Comment: @johnernaut When I did this. Checking to have `:online_search` be search or not did nothing. It will search online whether checked or un-checked. Putting in an address does not search online still.

Answer (score 1):

:online_search is a symbol, it will not never be nil.

However, if you want params[:online_search] to be skipped if its nil, you could try something like so:

```
q.with( *[params[:online_search], false].compact)
```

The * turns your array into parameters and the compact removes any nil values, removing params[:online_search], if it's empty.

So you'd get

```
q.with(false) # when params[:online_search] was empty
```

and

```
q.with('some value, false) # when params[:online_search] has data
```

Comment: if you have an array with nil values in it compact removes them: [1,nil,2,nil,3,nil,nil,5] => [1,2,3,5]

Comment: It seems nothing as change after playing around with it. Maybe it has something to do with my `cookie` in regards to `online_search`? I have edited my question and gave it more detail.